# RedisInsight: The 'MEMORY'' command is not supported in the redis instance

Tags: redis, redisinsights

Using RedisInsight GUI, when selecting a key in the Browser, I am getting a pop-up that says "The 'MEMORY'' command is not supported in the redis instance." and in the key vault viewer it says "Something went wrong fetching the value of key: [my key here]"

I am able to get the value just fine through CLI and through another GUI redis-commander.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the platform you're connecting to (AWS ElastiCache, MemoryStore, Azure Cache for Redis, VM, etc)?

Comment: Linux VM cluster w/ Redis 3.2.11

Comment: This version is ancient. Have you tried a more recent version (like 6.x)?

Comment: any solution to this as i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.10 of RedisInsight, support was added for some serializers

https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/release-notes/v2.10.0/

> Added support for additional data formats in Browser/Tree view,
> including Protobuf, Binary, Pickle, PHP unserialize (view and edit
> serialized PHP values as JSON), and Java serialized objects

In my case (using protobuf), I was getting the same error. Installing version 2.10 fixed my issue and I can see the value in RedisInsight.